# How do I track authentication in Laravel using satellizer

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, satellizer

I would like to count how many times a user has been logged in using Events in Laravel.

I am using third party library '**satellizer**' for authentication, and I have defined an AuthLoginEventHandler which looks as below:

```
<?php namespace App\Handlers\Events;

use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeQueued;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class AuthLoginEventHandler {

    /**
     * Create the event handler.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
         Log::info('Logged in User is working from constructor');
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  User $user
     * @param  $remember
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(User $user, $remember)
    {
        Log::info('Logged in');

        $user->login_counter = 1;
        $user->save();
        $user->increment('login_counter');
    }

}
```

In AuthenticationController I have:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    try {
        // verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials','status'=>false], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token','status'=>false], 500);
    }

    Log::info('Logged in User from JWT');
    Event::fire(new AuthLoginEventHandler());
    // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

The problem is the handle() method never gets called when I am firing the event from the authenticate() function inside AuthenticationController.

I can see the constructor is being called but not the handle function, WHat I am missing here, and is there any other way I could achieve such thing!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did changed authentication() function to this and it is working:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    try {
        // verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials','status'=>false], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token','status'=>false], 500);
    }

    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->increment('login_counter');
    $user->update();

    // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

And now the counter is working, so I can track the user logins, what would you think guys, is this some kind of solution? For me seems working fine, Why are we using Events when we can do this simple?

I would like to hear if anyone have a better solution for this